# How to set task level custom field value using jsom in project server 2013 ?

Tags: custom-fields, ms-project-server-2013, sharepoint-jsom

Is there a way to set a task level custom field value programmatically using jsom in Project Server 2013?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who's stuck on this, here's what is used.

```
set_item(your customGUID, value)
```